# How to configure lpsolve in anaconda3 and python 3.7 also in pycharm-2018.2.4 in ubuntu-14.04?

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, ubuntu-14.04, lpsolve

I want to use lpsolve package in pycharm-2018.2.4. Also I installed anaconda3 and python3.7. Using this link [install lpsolve](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14906603/how-to-install-lpsolve-module-for-python-on-linux-ubuntu-10-04) I downloaded and I got lpsolve55.so file. But I couldn't understand the steps in that link and I can't configure the path properly. Guide me with clear and step by procedure to install lpsolve and use it in pycharm environment in ubuntu-14.04. Thanks in advance.

Comment: shouldn't this PyCharm guide be used to install packages? [PyCharm 2018.3 Installing, Uninstalling and Upgrading Packages](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/installing-uninstalling-and-upgrading-packages.html)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.. As per your guidelines I try to install lpsolvers in pycharm  using conda package manager.. But I got the following error as " cddlib/lib-src/cddmp.h:31:18: fatal error: gmp.h: No such file or directory " .. How to resolve this error.. Thanks..

Answer (score 0):

https://pycddlib.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart.html#installation

The docs say it requires gmp.

Try `yum install gmp-devel` and then install it again.